# Namespacing database names on my server in order to test multiple different SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

An SSIS package that I'm building has two OLE DB connections, to databases named "core" and "staging". I created test versions of these two databases on my local SQL Server installation. I named them "test1_core" and "test1_staging". The "test1_" namespace is necessary because I have many SSIS different packages in active development at one time, and many of them refer to the same production databases. But it need each local SSIS package to refer to its own version of the database.

This works okay until I need to refer to the database name in the package specifically like in an Execute SQL task that includes two connections.

Also, I have SQL scripts that say `use [core]` at the top and I wish I could just use them on my local server without always having to open them up and change that line to `use [test1_core]` first, then having to change it back.

Is there some way to namespace the database name from within SQL Server so I can just refer to the local database as "core" from the SSIS package?

Comment: Must you use the `use` statement in your Execute SQL Tasks?

Comment: If your SQL can reference three-part objects inside of a common database, you could use synonyms to temporarily point them to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

When l was testing a large SSIS package l switched the data connections using the first technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497875/ssis-how-to-set-connection-string-dynamically-from-a-config-file).  The second technique in the second answer l have not tried but looks simpler to implement.  The main advantage was that l could easily switch between test and production.  Just wondering if that is easier than changing the namespace?

Comment: Add some of the details to your answer just in case the link goes stale.

Comment: The connection string and be built by using values stored in  variables.  Its a more complicated and requires a rather complex expression.  An added option is to stored the variables in a configuration file or database table means do not even have to open the SSIS package to change the connection string.